# Сжать .avi или .mp4 реально ли?

Tags: c++, c

возник вопрос: Возможно ли сжать видеофайлы или видеопоток?
Пытался использовать lz4 для сжатия данных, сначала использовал этот метод сжатия
https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/examples/blockStreaming_lineByLine.c
Он вообще не сжимает, а после сжатия даже размер файла выше оригинала.
В общем, вместо сжатия получил дополнительный лишний размер

Потом попробовал другой метод из lz4, с ними файл .mp4 формата сжался, размер файла уменьшился вдвое, однако, декомпрессию сделать lz4 не смог, на выходе пустой файл получаю. Собственно, почему видео файлы сжать невозможно или же я что-то не так делаю?

Дополнительно: я подумал, возможно дело в блоках данных, которые не повторяются, может из-за этого он и не может сжать данные? Что если используя Xor перемешать данные? К примеру, используя разный ключ Xor на каждые 32 байта чтобы вероятность совпдаения одинаковых байт возросло, а потом попробовать сжать LZ4 ? Получается что-то типа: Xor + LZ4 при компрессии и LZ4 + Xor для декомпрессии. 
Я далек от понимания всего этого, поэтому, жду ваших мыслей.

Comment: Вообще это от кодека зависит. Но большинство используемых кодеков это стандарты сжатия видео потока, т.е. по сути архиваторы. Так что ваш mp4 это уже сжатый файл. Причем коэффициенты сжатия видеокодеков гораздо выше чем у всяких lz4, потому что они знают как сжать видео с потерями так, что бы на глаз это было не различимо

Comment: И да, конечно повторов чего либо в видеопотоке практически нет, если бы они были, то соответствующую дополнительную архивацию заложили бы в кодек

Comment: А если мы используем какой нибудь IPTV стрим, там данные передаются в сжатом виде? Я хочу сжимать IPTV поток данных и передавать их на свой сервер. 
Получается, типа IPTV -> Server #1 -> Server #2

Я так же дополнил в теме метод с использованием Xor используя рандомные ключи на каждые 32 байта данных

Comment: любой mp4 и любой стрим может быть сжат с использованием любого кодека. Если стрим в хорошем качестве то наверняка он хорошо сжат, иначе бы для его передачи в реальном времени 100МБит не хватило

Comment: так что выясняйте что за кодек, если это какой нибудь mpeg-1, то его очень даже хорошо можно сжать. но для этого стоило бы использовать не lz4, а другой видео кодек, H-264 сожмет видео поток раз в 10 лучше lz4

Comment: Mike, то есть, идея с Xor не даст ничего?
Если продумать Xor ключи так чтобы байты повторялись. 
Сжимать каждые 32 байта разными ключами и эти ключи потом воткнуть в заголовок TCP пакета чтобы на моем втором сервере выдрать из заголовка Xor ключи, выполнить расжатие файла LZ4, а потом unXor'ить ключами

Comment: Если бы уже сжатые данные можно было бы сжимать еще, то мы бы до сих пор сидели на 640 кб

Comment: У вас ключи будут такой же длины как данные. И люди до вас уже озаботились идеей максимально сжимать видео при передаче и поэтому родилась масса видеокодеков, специально для этого предназначенных. Если бы они этого не сделали, вы бы перед просмотром ролика на ютубе сначала его скачивали раз в 50 дольше, чем он длиться. Вот, можете почитать что делают для этой цели современные кодеки: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264 Так что хотите сжать видео, возьмите кодек понижающий его качество

Comment: @Дан, у видеопотока высокая энтропия. Говоря простым языком — в нём почти нет повторяющихся последовательностей хотя бы из-за шумов (если поток сырой) или исходного компрессора (если поток сжатый).

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо ребята за помощь.

Comment: @Mike, скопируйте ваши комментарии в ответ, пожалуйста.